# Browser Awareness of Bluetooth Beacons / iBeacons

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Is there a way to make a browser aware of iBeacon devices in its proximity?

Similar to the way HTML5 Geolocation is working...

If not would this be something that can be achieved with a browser plug-in that can provide the detail to be consumed by javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  No web browsers have implemented any bridges between beacon detection and JavaScript.

I don't think a plugin approach is possible on mobile browsers (either iOS or Android), because neither browser supports asynchronous communication between external apps and JavaScript in Mobile Safari / Mobile Chrome. The best you could do is have a custom app that responds to a beacon, then launches a web page in the browser.  But I realize that isn't what you are asking for.

If you want to build a native app with JavaScript, you can use Cordova (aka PhoneGap) and use plugins that provide beacon support.  My company has one for our ProximityKit beacon framework:

https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/proximitykit-plugin-cordova

There is also a Cordova plugin that has basic beacon support here:

https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon

Comment: Excellent David!!! Thanks for pointing me in Cordova/PhoneGap's direction. It covers pretty much all I am after and is a good start... :)

Answer (score 3):

This looks promising (2016), Google Chrome developers site showing a desktop browser feature as a work in progress.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web?hl=en

> Even though the Web Bluetooth API specification is not finalized yet,
>   the Chrome Team is actively looking for enthusiastic developers (I
>   mean you) to try out this work-in-progress API and give feedback on
>   the spec and feedback on the implementation.
>
> Web Bluetooth API is currently available to be enabled experimentally
>   on your origin in Origin Trials, or locally on your machine using an
>   experimental flag. The implementation is partially complete and
>   currently available on Chrome OS, Chrome for Android M, Linux, and
>   Mac.
>
> Go to chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth, enable the highlighted
>   flag, restart Chrome and you should be able to scan for and connect to
>   nearby Bluetooth devices, read/write Bluetooth characteristics,
>   receive GATT Notifications and know when a Bluetooth device gets
>   disconnected.

https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md

Answer (score 2):

There's a W3C specification for this [Web Bluetooth](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/), but there's no support yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=bluetooth.

If you decide to write a Phonegap plugin implementing this spec will be a good starting point.